# Call fieldset multiple times

Tags: 7, webforms

I am using webforms in Drupal7, i give the user the option to enter multiple entries for one question. So for example, "how many players", if answer is 1, fieldset 1 opens and has name, address, number in it.

if answer is 2, fieldset 1 and fieldset two appear, 
if answer is 3, fielset 1, fieldset 2, and feildset 3.

if the answer is 2 or 3, I get this error: 
Conditional errors on page 2:
More than one conditional hides or shows component "One Player".
More than one conditional hides or shows component "Two Player".

so my plan was to create 10 fieldsets and have them display based on the # of players the user inputs.  I understand the error, but don't know of another way to achieve this.  [the one I came up with is just crazy and would mean so many of these inside fields, OMG ]

Any suggestions / guidance, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that stumbles on this.  I found a solution.  So remember my example is "How Many Players" [i used select option 1-5].  If user selects 1, fieldset 1 appears only, if he/she selects 2, FS1 and FS2 appear, select 3, FS1, FS2 and FS3 appear.  To prevent the error I use and or statement for allow the fieldset and worked my down down.  See image.[image]